# How to do localStorage foreach dropdown to remember selected value after get method

Tags: jquery, ajax, filter

How to do localStorage foreach dropdown to remember the selected value after get?

I want that all dropdowns stay on the selected item, so if I use the get method it stays on the correct value.

I have no idea how to fix this.

html dropdowns code:

```
   <ul class="filter-box">
        <li class="filter">

            <select name="sortby" class="filter_all orderby">
                <option value="date_down">Datum: (aflopend)</option>
                <option value="date_up">Datum: (oplopend)</option>
                <option value="name_up">Naam (aflopend)</option>
                <option value="name_down">Naam (oplopend)</option>
            </select>
        </li>

        <li class="filter">

            <select name="emailCheck" class="filter_all mailCheck">
                <option value="">Kies een optie</option>
                <option value="email-send-yes">Verstuurd ( ja )</option>
                <option value="email-send-no">Verstuurd ( nee )</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li class="filter">
        <select name="downloadCheck" class="filter_all downloadCheck">
                <option value="">Kies een optie</option>
                <option value="status_download">Status (gedownload)</option>
                <option value="status_new">Status (nieuw)</option>
                <option value="status_updated">Status (geupdate)</option>
            </select>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Ajax/jQuery script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
              
              filter_data();

              function filter_data() {
            
                  $('#customers');
                  var action = 'fetch_data';
                  var orderby = get_filter('orderby');
                  var mailCheck = get_filter('mailCheck');
                  var downloadCheck = get_filter('downloadCheck');
                  var get_status_value = "<?php echo $get_status_value; ?>";
                  var current_page = "<?php echo $page; ?>";
                  var limit = "<?php echo $limit; ?>";
                  $.ajax({
                      url: "filter-script.php",
                      method: "POST",
                      data: {
                          action: action,
                          orderby: orderby,
                          mailCheck: mailCheck,
                          downloadCheck: downloadCheck,
                          limit: limit,
                          current_page: current_page,
                          get_status_value: get_status_value
                      },
                      success: function(data) {
                  
                          $('#customers').html(data);
                          // alert(data);
                      }
                  });
              }

              function get_filter(class_name) {
                  var filter = [];
                  $('.' + class_name).each(function() {
                      filter.push($(this).val());
                  });
                 localStorage.setItem('filter', filter);
                  console.log(filter);
                  return filter;
              }

              $('.filter_all').on('change', function() {
                  filter_data();
              });
          });
</script>
```

Any idea how to do this? Or any idea how i can filter with AJAX/PHP with pagination via the get method.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well your question, you can make a use of the `.prop('selectedIndex', i)` method of Jquery where i is the index of the option you want to be selected. So make sure you select the correct select like `$('#selectEmail').prop('selectIndex', i)`